# selecting an element in jquery for later reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
    var star = $("._container > favorite");
    var symbol =  $(star.parentNode.parentNode).attr("symbol");
    var exchange = $(star.parentNode.parentNode).attr("exchange");
```

However, if I then look at symbol and exchange, they are blank. I know that "star" is there  for I can reference through:

```
$("._container > .favorite").click(function() {
```

What's the correct way of doing this?

Using the following code, the second alert does not show up:

```
var star = $("._container > .favorite");
alert("symbol1");
var symbol = star.parent.parent.attr("symbol");
var exchange = star.parent.parent.attr("exchange");
alert("symbol2");
```

Here's the relevant html:

```
   <div id="tabs-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true" style="display: block;" tabcounter="2" symbol="GOOG" exchange="NASDAQ">

   <div class="_container">           
   <span class="favorite" status="off" style="display: inline;">   ☆</span>
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML too.

Comment: I haven't tried, but can't you use this "star.parentNode.parentNode.attr("symbol");" instead of this "$(star.parentNode.parentNode).attr("symbol");"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use parent.parent. Use closest() to find the closest node that you want. I think that you are refering it wrong
Here is the documentation http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 1):

```
var $str_par_par = star.parent().parent(),
    symbol = $str_par_par.attr("symbol"),
    exchange = $str_par_par.attr("exchange");
```

---

By [Arun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114251/arun-p-johny)

`star.parentNode` should be undefined because star is a jQuery object, not a dom element reference which has the parentNode property

Comment: hm, still nothing comes up if I put in an alert

Comment: the html is buried within other stuff so it's a bit of a mess to throw it in fiddle, however I've added a second alert which still doesn't show up

Comment: @user1357015 It's quite hard to debug if we don't know your `HTML` structure.

Comment: @Nick I've added the relevant html. To get a jsfiddle going, i'd need to add a lot of other stuff. hopefully this is enough!